# How to fix "E: Unable to locate package "

Tags: package, ubuntu-18.04

Let it be removing or changing the directory , i keep getting this error popping . Thanks in advance.

```
     User@blue--drift:~$ rm rtlwifi_new
     rm: cannot remove 'rtlwifi_new': Is a directory
     User@blue--drift:~$ sudo apt-get remove rtlwifi_new
     [sudo] password for kamalesh: 
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building dependency tree       
     Reading state information... Done
     E: Unable to locate package rtlwifi_new
```

Comment: You might want to use your favorite search engine to look “delete directory Linux”

Answer (score 1):

```
rm -Rf rtlwifi_new
```

But please do some research before posting.